# Httppost in groovy and grails

Tags: grails, groovy

May I have sample codes to do manual http post in groovy and grails? I'm trying to post some strings to server.

Comment: If you're just testing an existing service manually, I'd use curl on the command line for that.  Otherwise, check out httpbuilder, lots of examples there (http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a POST request from the browser to the Grails app, then just use `<g:form>`

```
<g:form name="myForm" url="[action:'list',controller:'book']">...</g:form>
```

By default Grails forms use the POST HTTP method.

If you want to send a POST to your Grails app, but don't want to build a form, there are about a million browser plugins/IDE plugins/desktop apps that allow you to construct HTTP requests. Examples include the REST Console plugin for Chrome and the HTTP Client plugin for Eclipse.

If you want to send a POST from your Grails app to some other URL, you'll need to use a Java/Groovy HTTP library to construct the request. Options include HTTPBuilder (Groovy) or Apache HTTP Client (Java).

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way,

Use an editor to a page (like below), open it in browser, click submit button

```
<form method="POST" action="http://slashdot.org/controller/action">
<input type=hidden name='boo' value='foo'>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

edit page, reload, repeat.